# Codeigniter Mpdf image not shown in header

Tags: image, codeigniter, mpdf

I've a problem with mpdf and Codeigniter: i'm printing an html page right if I load just simple text.
If I add an image in my header by

```
$mpdf->setHTMLHeader(site_url("assets/img/my_image.jpg"));
```

The browser load for minutes and then download a pdf file with a red X intead of my image. It seems my image link is broken, but it's not: i've checked it.
I've thought it could be a permission issue so I changed my img folder's and files permissions to 777, but nothing has changed...

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: this might help https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/image.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in relative path for image, even if the web browser is fine with them and display the images correctly.

Try to generate a path with an absolute base URL.

```
<img src="full_path/assets/img/my_image.jpg', true) ?>" alt="my_image" />
```

Or try to use base64 image.

Also you can set debug to true and see what is error (sometimes is GD extension)
`$this->_mpdf->showImageErrors = true`;